# Repeating alarm runs more than once

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm, android-alarms, repeatingalarm

```
    Intent myAlarm = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent recurringAlarm = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.getApplicationContext(), 0, myAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar updateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    alarms.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, updateTime.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY / 3, recurringAlarm);
```

Say this piece of code is executed more than once. This results in that many alarms being created (I find this info from dumpsys where it says X# wakes - X# alarms).

I've been told that setting the same request code and same intent cannot start the alarm the second time.